# Pseudocode for Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, pseudocode

I need to write pseudocode to implement a class of car using only the information below. Can anyone help?

Class: Race Car
Attributes: 
Year
Make
Model
Type
Color
Maximum Speed
0-60 Speed
Quarter Mile Speed
Horse Power

Comment: Why? I know nothing about this field. I would like to learn.

Comment: @user2442128 you're asking a question like can you please do my homework? SO helps who shows interest in programming.  Hope you understood.

Answer (score 2):

Here is pseudocode. I used only your information.

```
Class: Race Car 
    Attribute: Year
    Attribute: Make 
    Attribute: Model 
    Attribute: Type 
    Attribute: Color 
    Attribute: Maximum 
    Attribute: Speed 
    Attribute: 0-60 
    Attribute: Speed 
    Attribute: Quarter 
    Attribute: Mile 
    Attribute: Speed 
    Attribute: Horse 
    Attribute: Power
```

it's joke ;)